# getElementById twice for Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, getelementbyid

how can i get nodeName?

```
if(system.ie) {
    var oDiv = document.all[id];
    var link = oDiv.all.item(position); 
    console.log(link.nodeName);
    } else {
        var oDiv = document.getElementById(id);
        ???
    }
```

for firefox

Comment: `id`s must be unique so why are you using `document.all` (which is never necessary and does not work in IE >=11)? - Use `getElementById` without worrying about the user agent.  Whats wrong with `document.getElementById(id).nodeName` ?;

Comment: For Firefox or Internet Explorer? Because you have both tags.

Comment: it work in ie. need for firefox

Comment: @AlexK. diffrent values in ie and firefox

Comment: @Dmitry Where does `position` come from?